# Como poner el puntero al final de una linea en php

Tags: php

Buenas tengo el siguiente fichero de texto

```
juan,123,
josloplop8,123456,
Maria,123456,
José Antonio,123456,
```

El primer dato de la tupla son los usuarios el segundo las contraseñas.
Me gustaria saber como puedo posicionarme al final de una linea para escribir en ella con php

El codigo que tengo implentado ahora mismo es

```
$fichero = fopen("datos.txt", "a+"); 
while (!feof($fichero)){ //Recorremos el fichero linea a linea buscando el nombre del usuario
$linea = fgets($fichero);
if (str_contains($linea, ($_POST["nombreUsuario"]))) {



}
```

}

Podria alguien ayudarme porfavor?

Comment: Considera usar [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) y [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: No entiendo como quieres que use esos metodos para poner el puntero al final de la linea

Answer (score 1):

En tu código no estás leyendo el archivo fila por fila, deberías abrir un `while` basado en `fgets()`.

Por otra parte, deberías verificar primero que el `$_POST` tiene ese dato, no sea que te metas al trapo a modificar archivos cuando puedes tener un *`Undefined index`*.

Sugiero este código, lo que hace es crear un archivo temporal con los eventuales nuevos datos y luego reemplaza el archivo original por el temporal. Esto es lo más eficiente, sobre todo en archivos grandes, pues no es buena idea modificar en archivo mientras lo lees al mismo tiempo.

```
$toSearch=$_POST["nombreUsuario"] ?? NULL;    
if ($toSearch) 
{
    $srcName='datos.txt';
    $tmpName='datos.tmp';        
    $scrFile = fopen($srcName, 'r');
    $tmpFile = fopen($tmpName, 'w');
    $isChanged = false;        
    if ($scrFile && $tmpFile) 
    {
        while (($line = fgets($scrFile)) !== false) 
        {
            if (str_contains($line, $toSearch)) 
            {
                $newLine = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
                $line = sprintf("%sEsto es nuevo,\n",$newLine);
                $isChanged = true;
            }
            fputs($tmpFile, $line);
        }
        fclose($scrFile);
        fclose($tmpFile);        
        if ($isChanged)
        {
            rename($tmpName, $srcName);
        } 
        else 
        {
            unlink($tmpName);
        }
    }        
}
```

Si por ejemplo, el valor de `$toSearch` es `juan`, el archivo quedará así:

```
juan,123,Esto es nuevo,
josloplop8,123456,
Maria,123456,
José Antonio,123456,
```

Si quieres verificar solamente la primera parte de cada línea (los datos antes de la primera coma), deberías usar `explode`, pero eso no queda claro en tu pregunta y si quieres implementarlo, no será complicado hacerlo.

Cualquier duda, deja en comentario al pie de esta respuesta.